# Можно ли реализовать чтение данных с сайта и обновление базы данных на Python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Хочу иметь сайт, на котором размещена некоторая информация. Эта информация хранится в базе данных и должна постоянно автоматически пополняться путём парсинга некого сайта.

1. Возможно ли написать такое на Python?
2. Насколько хороша для этой задачи связка Python + Django?
3. Что мне потребуется для размещения такого приложения в интернете? Только VPS, или может быть что-то проще?

P.S. Знаю, как такое написать на Java, но это самостоятельный учебный проект и я слышал, что для веба у нас Python хорош.
P.S.S. Это всё, что я знаю о Python.

Comment: Python для парсинга сайтов вполне подходит. Правда, возможно потребуется доставить дополнительные компоненты типа lxml.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а там есть возможность запустить что-то выполняться постоянно, в фоне? Я просто провожу аналогию между Питоном и PHP, и в PHP такое было сделать сложновато.

Comment: Бесконечный цикл, в нем получение данных, парсинг, сохранение, пауза в N секунд и все по новой.

Comment: Питон подойдёт, но стоит иметь ввиду, что порог входа в Django достаточно высокий.

Comment: @ssh, Надеюсь, осилю. Пожалуйста, ответьте на 3 вопрос.

Comment: @Dazar VPS потребуется, да. VPS -- это виртуальный выделенный сервер, то есть ограничений в сравнении с полноценным физическим Linux сервером там нет никаких.

Comment: @Dazar и вместо Django рекомендую Flask

Comment: @ssh, расскажите в двух словах, почему Flask? И я знаю, что такое VPS, неоднократно им пользовался, просто я думал, может обойтись обычным хостингом? И кстати, а может вообще данные собирать другим приложением, и отправлять в веб-приложение, например, через REST-запросы

Comment: Flask имеет существенно более низкий порог вхождения, имхо. Если есть уже написанный на Java код, то почему бы не завести его на сервере и отдавать данные в виде JSON? Тогда останется только написать клиентскую часть вообще без Python.

Comment: @Dazar Если вы не знаете ни Python, ни Django, то почти наверняка не справитесь. Попытка написать сразу нормально на неизвестном ЯП обычно успехом не кончается. Python имеет свою философию, отличную от Java. Он хоть и проще, но переучиваться придется. Enterprise и веб -- вещи не диаметрально противоположные. Сайты и на Java пишут.

Comment: @ssh спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27506/discussion-between-dazar-and-ssh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Да. Для парсинга популярны библиотеки:

   - `requests` + `beautifulsoup`
   - `scrapy`
   - `grab`
   - `selenium` (если контент страницы генерируется динамически [например, AJAXом])
2. В зависимости от необходимого временного промежутка между парсами можно использовать как бесконечный цикл, так и cron или celery
3. Django будет хорош благодаря своей `ORM`.
   Помимо `VPS` есть ещё `Google App Engine`, но там поддерживается только старая `Django` (1.4, кажется). Можете попробовать `pythonanywhere`

Comment: [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) пишется с одной `p`. `grab` пакет гораздо менее известен (его упоминание не слишком уместно здесь).

Answer (score 3):

1. Конечно возможно. Python, вероятно, самый популярный язык для парсинга данных с сайта. Для этого в библиотеке языка присутствует огромное множество инструментов, рекомендую начать изучать парсинг с `beautifulsoup4`
2. Да, Python + Django подойдет. Впринципе, Вы можете написать сам сайт на чем угодно (хоть на PHP), и периодически запускать скрипт на Python, который будет обновлять базу данных. Единственное "но": сделать это в связке будет немного удобнее, так как Вы можете использовать Django ORM как для самого сайта, так и для сохранения спарсенных данных
3. Самый доступных вариант это действительно VPS. Как вариант, и если позволяет бюджет, можете попробовать специализированный хостинг под Django -- там будет проще разобраться с настройками. Например [этот](https://hosting4django.net/#firstPage)(это первое, что нашел в Гугле)